# How to listen for double-click on jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jstree, double-click

How would I write a listener for a double-click event on a jstree object? (For example, I'd like to double-click on a tree node and paste its anchor's `href` value into an `input` field in a form somewhere.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I attach custom behaviour to a double click in jsTree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674625/how-can-i-attach-custom-behaviour-to-a-double-click-in-jstree)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have used something like this way back a year ago, i don't know if there's any change in the current jstree version :

```
jstree.bind("dblclick.jstree", function (event) {
   var node = $(event.target).closest("li");
   var data = node.data("jstree");
   // Do some action
});
```

**node :** Contains the li that is being clicked.

**data :** Contains the metadata.

Comment: After `// Do some action`, if I add `alert(data);` then I get `null`.

Comment: This SO answer is close to yours and seems to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674625/how-can-i-attach-custom-behaviour-to-a-double-click-in-jstree/5652753#5652753

Comment: node.data("jstree") is returning undefined in latest version ofjStree(3.1.x)
So use this: `var tree = $(this).jstree();
   var node = tree.get_node(evt.target);
   var nodePath = tree.get_path(node).join("/");`
So you have both node object and tree object to invoke any tree API

Answer (score 6):

Nirmal's solution works if you click anywhere on the jstree div. I wanted to enable double click only on the nodes themselves and not, for example, on the whitespace to the right. changing the solution a little enabled this:

```
$('#jstree-div a').live('dblclick',function (e) {
    var node = $(e.target).closest("li");
    var type = node.attr('rel');
    var item = node[0].id;

    // do stuff...
});
```

Not sure why the 'rel' and the 'id' attributes are in different places in the resulting node, but it works ;)