# How to get the Node data during double click processing in jsTree?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'm using the jsTree jQuery plugin and I want to process the Node data after double click. For single click, the code is simple, as there is the `data` parameter:

```js
.bind("select_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
     if(jQuery.data(data.rslt.obj[0], "href")) {
         window.location=jQuery.data(data.rslt.obj[0], "href");
     } else {
         alert("No href defined for this element");
     }
})
```

But how to access the same data in case of double click?

```js
.bind("dblclick.jstree", function(e) {
    ???
})
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674625/how-can-i-attach-custom-behaviour-to-a-double-click-in-jstree

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932876/how-to-listen-for-double-click-on-jstree

Answer (score 2):

This Works

To access the same data in case of double click

```
.bind("dblclick.jstree", function(e) {

var data= $(treeID).jstree().get_selected(true);

})
```